# Compare date with db field AM/PM and current time?

Tags: codeigniter

I have a DB field (pickup_time) with (varchar)
That result is like this = 01 : 55 : AM
And I want to compare with the current time with php, so before 30 minutes of pickup_time, I want to show a button.
plz help me I am stuck(Codeigniter).

```
$trp_time=$row->pickup_time;
$time_now=date('h:i A',$trp_time);
$res=strtotime('h:i A',$trp_time);
$diff= round(abs($time_now-$res)/60,2);
The above code is not worked for me.
Before 30 minutes of pickup time i want a button is to be get eanble.
```

Comment: Please show what you have attempted.

Comment: provide some code so we can help

Comment: Why that value is not stored as DateTime in first place?